# Understanding placing images in Kinetic.JS?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, kineticjs

Below I have some code for an assignment I'm working on. Having been placed in a 2nd year course without taking foundations of JavaScript, I'm kind of in a rut.

I'm trying to place three images, and be able to call on them later with functions to change their opacity.

When I have the images placed, only one seems to want to appear at a time, and when I call to them, I'm told that they don't exist.

```
// Create the canvas based on the existing div for it in the HTML file

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage
({
    container: 'canvasContainer',
    width: 600,
    height: 600
});

  /* /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    C O D E   F O R   L O A D I N G   U P   I M A G E S
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////// */

    var characters = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(characters);

    window.onload = function()
    {

        var majoraCharacter = new Image();

        majoraCharacter.src ="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg"

        majoraCharacter.onload = function()
        {
        character1= new Kinetic.Image({ x: 400, y: 300, width: 150, height: 150, offset: {x: 75, y: 75}, image: majoraCharacter});
        characters.add(character1);
        characters.draw();
        }

    }

    window.onload = function()
    {

        var amaterasuCharacter = new Image();

        amaterasuCharacter.src ="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg"

        amaterasuCharacter.onload = function()
        {
        character2= new Kinetic.Image({ x: 400, y: 200, width: 150, height: 150, offset: {x: 75, y: 75}, opacity:0.5, image: amaterasuCharacter});
        characters.add(character2);
        characters.draw();
        }

    }

    window.onload = function()
    {

        var toothlessCharacter = new Image();

        toothlessCharacter.src ="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg"

        toothlessCharacter.onload = function()
        {
        character3= new Kinetic.Image({ x: 400, y: 100, width: 150, height: 150, offset: {x: 75, y: 75}, image: toothlessCharacter});
        characters.add(character3);
        characters.draw();
        }

    }



  /* /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          C A N V A S   F U N C T I O N A L I T Y
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////// */

      // Create new layer for background images

      // Create layer for character images

      var character = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        fill: 'grey',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        offset: {x: 75, y: 75},
      });

      // add the shape to the layer
      character.add(rect);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(character);
```

Is there a way I can better add images to canvas?

And what is preventing them from co-existing, and being editable outside of their loading functions?

Any and all answers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Bf88D/

Some KineticJS basics:

- KineticJS starts with a stage.
- The stage is a container for one or more layers which are added to the stage
- Each layer is actually a canvas
- Shapes (including images) are added to a layer.

Since you're new to javascript, here's an outline of how to structure your project

- just use one window.onload and put all your javascript in that one window.onload
- load all images in advance so they are available to draw on your canvas
- When all the images are loaded, then create Kinetic.Image objects from them.

Here's an image loader that loads all your images in advance and then calls the `start` function when your images are fully loaded.

```
// image loader

var imageURLs=[];  // put the paths to your images here
var imagesOK=0;
var imgs=[];
imageURLs.push("");
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){
    // the imgs[] array holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]
    // use the images now!
}
```

After you have all your images loaded, you can use this reusable function to add Kinetic Images on the layer.

- You send in one image that you've loaded in advance.
- You also send in the x,y position where you want the image located.
- You also send in the width,height that you want the image resized to.

This function adds one new image to the layer

```
function addKineticImage(image,x,y,w,h){
    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
        x:x,
        y:y,
        width:w,
        height:h,
        image:image,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(image);
    layer.draw();
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are seriously awesome.

Thank you so much for your advice lol